# What is the practical limit for the quantity of entities listed in a claim based peoplepicker?

Tags: claims-based-auth, people-picker

What is the practical limit for the quantity of entities listed in a claim based peoplepicker in SharePoint 2010?
Is there a limit? We are trying to get a list of 200,000+ plus users to work in the people picker on a SharePoint site using Claims based authentication and I am not so sure that is practical.

TIA
J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match limit for the Entity Picker is 100.